# Get changes to SQL Server CE database using track changes/Sync Framework

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

We are developing an application (C# / .NET Framework 4) which will be using MS Sync Framework.

Track changes will be enabled on the client SQL Server CE 3.5 database. As such, I would like to piggy back on the track changes to use the data in the application. I want to be able to retrieve the current New, Changed and Deleted information from SQL Server CE Track Changes and display this data in the UI to the user. I have found lots of information on using sync framework to manage the synchronization, but how can I pull this data into the application to know about database changes in the UI? We are using entity framework, and Linq to SQL.

Is there some way I can make entity framework aware of the Track Changes information? Or even just Linq queries to grab the data?

We can not just use Entity Framework change tracking information as this needs to be persistent between application restarts and even back end data changes.

Answer (score 0):

try something similar to this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2011/03/02/synchronization-services-for-ado-net-for-devices-improving-performance-by-skipping-tables-that-don-t-need-synchronization.aspx